# Laravel get count from model relationship

Tags: laravel

I have this 3 model.

```
Author
|id|name|

Post
|id|author_id|

Likes
|id|post_id|
```

The relationship.

Author

```
public function post()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Post::class, 'author_id', 'id');                                             
}
```

Post

```
public function author(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Author::class, 'id', 'author_id');
}

public function likes(){
    return $this->hasMany(Likes::class, 'post_id', 'id');
}
```

Likes

```
public function post()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Post::class, 'id', 'post_id');
}
```

My problem is, how to list all Authors with total likes from all of his posts.

Using call $authors->posts->likes results an error because posts returns a collection.

Comment: You need to define hasManyThrough relationship

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Author** hasMany posts, and **Post** hasMany likes. 
To achieve all *likes* from the **Author** model,   you can define a **[hasManyThrough()](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through)** relationship :

```
public function likes()
{
   return $this->hasManyThrough(
       'App\Likes', // Likes model
       'App\Post', // Post model
       'author_id', // Foreign key on posts table...
       'post_id', // Foreign key on likes table...
       'id', // Local key on authors table...
       'id' // Local key on posts table...
   );
}
```